# Check if a list of dates contains a particular date

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I am looking for a better way checking if a `List` of `java.util.Date` objects (`ArrayList`, which is returned to me). The scenario is, I am returned a `List` of dates, and I would like to find out if a date I have on hand is within the `List` of dates I was returned.

Currently what I am doing is looping the List and using JodaTime to compare the dates.

Note: Only the date part should be considered while comparing the dates (not the time part).

Comment: You want a HashMap/HashSet so you can find it in O(1) time?

Comment: More details please. Do you have a list of java.util.Date objects? Strings? some other kind of date representation?

Comment: I have a List of java.util.Date objects.

Comment: How about telling us if the list is sorted in any particular order or just random?

Comment: Hi Andy, there is no order. Thx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write your own [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). You could use this to perform the individual comparisons of the `Date` objects

```
public class MyDateComparator implements Comparator<Date> {
    protected static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    public int compare(Date d1, Date d2) {
        return DATE_FORMAT.format(d1).compareTo(DATE_FORMAT.format(d2));
    }
}


Date myDate = ...
List<Date> listOfDates = ...
Collections.sort(listOfDates);
int index = Collections.binarySearch(listOfDates, myDate, new MyDateComparator());
if (index >= 0) {
  // you found me
}
```

(typed with fat fingers on iPad, rocking 3 month old to sleep, apologies for minor mistakes)

Comment: You can modify the Comparator as like, or supply different ones as you need. The only thing I don't like about the binary search is that it doesn't return an array on indicies, but that's another question all together

Comment: I like using Java Comparator/Comparable since it is the recommended way. But not sure if I should convert java.util.Date to JodaTime's DateTime and use JodaTime for the date comparison within the Comparator. Your take on this?

Comment: It's entirely up to you. You have to weigh the cost of the time (in development time & execution time), as well as the memory over head against the convince of the solution. The primary reason for using the Comparator/Comparable API is that it is well supported in the overall Java API. At the end of the day Joda Time is still only using the Comarator API, it's just richer then the one I've demonstrated ;)

Comment: New user @santaji proposed an edit: `Collections.sort(listOfDates,new MyDateComparator());` stating "listOfDates needs to be sorted using MyDateComparator() then only Collections.binarySearch() will work." I've rejected his edit.

Comment: `if (index != -1)`  should be `if (index >= 0)` otherwise bad things happen

Answer (score 1):

Two java.util.Date objects are equal() if they resolve to the same millisecond. So you can use List.contains():

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29

```
List<Date> dates = ...
Date targetDate = ...
if (dates.contains(targetDate)) { ... }
```

Alternatively, if you know the list is sorted you could use Collections.binarySearch()

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20java.lang.Object%29

Comment: Sorry only the date components are considered, the time component cannot be used for comparison in my case.

Comment: But whats the searching method `Lists`'s `contains()` use? I believe he should use some sort of searching method that is best in this situation. Unless `contains()` already does this. This what I just said is mute lol.

Comment: @ChinBoon: Oh, I misunderstood. In that case looping and using JodaTime is probably the way to go. As an aside, make sure to use the correct time zone when doing the comparison.